How capture esc keydown event while audio element captures it
As you can see in this demo
 <audio controls src="/media/cc0-audio/t-rex-roar.mp3"></audio>

When you click on the play button and then hit the escape key, the audio elements captures it.
In my angular app, the audio element sits inside a dialog which I would like to close when the escape button is clicked. But whatever I try, I never receive the keydown event.
Is there a way I can make sure that the audio element lets the keywdown through or ignores it?
Update: This seems to work
 audio.addEventListener('play', () => {
      audio.blur();
 });

But I'm not sure if this is an ideal solution. I can imagine that this whole focus thing has a reason to be there in the first place. So is there maybe another way to listen for keyboard events leaving the focus as is?

to the duplicate, you just need to combine the keypresses event with the information that the audio plays.

@JeanlucaScaljeri please share a stackblitz where the issue happens on the question, will reopen the question, there is no minmal reproducible code.

Here a demo: https://stackblitz.com/edit/vitejs-vite-9vzcnj?file=index.html&terminal=dev. As soon as you hit play, the button gets focus and events are not received anymore
